# grouping controls together for UI purposes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm looking for a way to group together number of controls in a thin border like in the bellow picture, in c# this can be achieved in different ways (panel, group etc.) how can I achieve this is objective-c (there are 3 controls two labels and a slider)

[image]

Comment: You mean you want to draw a box around them?

Answer (score 1):

Add all of the views as subviews of a `UIView`, where the 'container' view is the desired size of the box. Import QuartzCore.h. Get the layer of the container view and set its border width and color.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] init];

// add subviews

containerView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
containerView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
```

Comment: for some reason instead of getting a rectangle in the size of the UIView i get a line, also in the IB and runtime the objects contained in the view are aligned differently

Comment: You need to set the autoresizing / autolayout rules for both the container view and the content views to ensure they maintain appropriate size and position when displayed.

Answer (score 0):

YOu also have to set up the autoresizing mask of subviews in your uiview and the uiview itself